# Chrome doesn't always repeat events with JavaScript setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, setinterval, repeat

I want to display several images of the same size at the same position, one at a time, with a 5s interval between each change. To do so I've used jQuery.Timer, that uses setInterval() to call some show_next_image() function every 5s.

It actually does work with IE, Opera, Safara, Firefox and.. partly with Google Chrome. It's not working with Google Chrome if I open a new window and directly type my website URL: it'll show the second image and stop. And with any other situation (reload, from another link, not right after opening a new window) it'll badly work: one can see the back image before the front image is shown.

Thus I'm wondering whether I've done something wrong with my JavaScript source. What I do is I use a front and a back image. When I want to show the next image, the back img source is set to the new image, and the front image is faded out while the back one is faded in through jQuery. You can check it out at http://www.laurent-carbon.com/ (in French). The two img are identified with bg1 and bg2.

```
var images = ["/img/IMG_0435bg.jpg", "/img/IMG_0400bg.jpg", "/img/maisonnette 2.jpg", "/img/IMG_0383bg.jpg", "/img/IMG_0409bg.jpg", "/img/IMG_0384bg.jpg"];
var idx = 1;
var waitTime = 5000; // ms

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bg2").hide();
    $.timer(waitTime, load_next);
    $.preLoadImages(images);
});

function load_next(timer) {
    var toshow = images[idx];
    idx++;
    idx %= images.length;

    back_image().attr('src', toshow);

    swap_images();
}

function front_image() {
    return (idx % 2 == 0) ? $("#bg1") : $("#bg2");
}

function back_image() {
    return (idx % 2 == 0) ? $("#bg2") : $("#bg1");
}

function swap_images() {
    back_image().fadeOut('slow');
    front_image().fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Thanks,
Ceylo

Comment: I'm not sure if I can reproduce. I just see `IMG_0435bg.jpg` only, even when refreshing.

Comment: This code could be a lot simpler I think. Are you open to suggestions involving a little restructuring?

Comment: @Joseph: For sure, don't hesitate.

Comment: @pimvdb: which web browser are you using?

Comment: @pimvdb: great.. I've some improvement to do...

Comment: Well, I could get rid of the back image being shortly visible (I'd inverted back and front...):
 var back = back_image();
 var front = front_image();
 front.fadeOut('slow');
 back.fadeIn('slow');

Comment: ...where is this `$.preLoadImages()` defined?

Comment: @levi: woops. It was taken from http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript (and slightly modified to use the images var instead of 'arguments'). I've dropped the function here to shorten the source code, but I forgot to drop the preLoadImages() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've worked out a solution .... without the use of plugins.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PvPXM/9/show

### source

http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PvPXM/9/

This approach is a lot cleaner and removes the problem I had while viewing your page in chrome: the animation getting out of sync and flashing.

The only thing you have to do in the HTML is wrap the two images in a `<div id="fadeBox" style="position:relative"></div>`

```
$(function() {
    var images = [
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/IMG_0435bg.jpg",
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/IMG_0400bg.jpg",
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/maisonnette 2.jpg",
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/IMG_0383bg.jpg",
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/IMG_0409bg.jpg",
        "http://www.laurent-carbon.com/img/IMG_0384bg.jpg"
        ];
    var idx = 1;
    var max = images.length;
    var easing = "swing";
    var waitTime = 5000; // ms
    var fadeTime = 2000; // ms
    var fadeShow = function(fadeTime, fadeDelay) {
        var $topImage = $("#fadeBox img:last");
        $topImage.fadeTo(fadeDelay, 1, function() {
            $topImage.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0, easing, function() {
                $topImage
                    .fadeTo(0, 1)
                    .insertBefore("#fadeBox img:first")
                    .attr("src", images[++idx == max ? idx = 0 : idx]);
                fadeShow(fadeTime, fadeDelay);
            });
        });
    };

    fadeShow(fadeTime, waitTime);
});
```

Hope this helps

PS thanks to Levi for cleaning the code up a bit.

Comment: +1 for not using a plug-in but still keeping it customizable.  However, I'd recommend that you look at http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PvPXM/9/.  It's the same code, just cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, Levi :) may I use this link in my post?

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. Got it to work (well.. I didn't do much in it..). The only point is that the second image appears first, and is then quickly faded to show the first one, also quickly faded to re-show the second one. Then everything goes well. It's not really annoying so I think I'll stick with it unless I really have time to waste.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/RxyZY/**

**Notes:**

- **You are trying to reinvent the wheel.**  You are creating a simple slideshow.  There are numerous plugins to do exactly this and much more.  I used [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) in my example, which is [extremely customizable](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).
- **You should wrap your stuff up in a function, creating an expression.** In my example, the `(function($){}(jQuery))` is what does the trick.  It scopes your variables to the function, rather than the global namespace.

Comment: some people prefer code designed for a specific situation over plugins.  Even with customizability one size does not fit all.

Comment: @Joseph While agree with you, it is my experience that people will eventually give the job to someone else, and the new person would rather work with a plug-in with good documentation and one they are probably familiar with more than learning some new custom one.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Documentation is definitely a killer when it comes to custom code.

Comment: @levi: thank you for both notes. I'm quite new to both javascript and jQuery (1 week) thus I chose what was the most straightforward way to me. Just doing a fading effect seemed quite simple, that's why I haven't looked for an already done solution. Moreover, I wasn't even aware that there were so many jQuery plugins for everything. So.. newbies mistake, same for namespace thing.